# Permission denied in logs from time to time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

From time to time, everytime I want to clear cache or something related I got this error:

```
 Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "laravel_system/storage/logs/laravel-2019-01-28.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /laravel_system/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:13761
```

The entire Log folder has www-data:www-data and 777 permissions, but when this happens there are some log files that are either with ubuntu or www-data or don't have 777 permissions.

It's not really a big problem, I just change permissions for the folder again and config:cache works again...but I wonder what I'm missing here since it happens every now and then.

Comment: Do you have any crons or worker running in the background? They could well be running under a different user.

Comment: ^ And are you running artisan commands under the same user that the web server is using?

Comment: @Abulafia I don't think so. I only have supervisor for queueing emails and LogViewer in order to see the error logs.

Comment: @Devon No, I'm using ubuntu user and the web server is www-data (or at least that's what I think...it's Ngninx)

Comment: Well, that's going to cause any new log files to be owned by two different users.